# SSH to a non default port times out over Android hotspot connection

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-16.04, android

I'm trying to connect to a remote Ubuntu machine using ssh protocol. My local OS is Ubuntu 16.04 and the remote OS is 18.04. My local machine is connected to my Android 5 over shared hotspot connection.

On the server machine, the default ssh port(22) has been closed due to security considerations, but the port 6022 has been opened instead.

I've already tested SSH connection from my Android phone to the server using orange SSH and it works well, however, I get a timeout error after a while on my Ubuntu machine when trying to connect. I guess the android doesn't allow connections over a non-default port(in this case 6022). Any idea? Thanks

Note: I'm trying to connect to the server using a password. There's also a private and public key on my laptop which I use for another server.

Update: I suppose I have to use Port Forwarding since I couldn't find a way to open the port on my Android device.

Comment: Check that your mobile provider has not blocked the connection.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've already checked it via JuiceSSH. It connects properly.

Comment: Having exactly the same problem, I used JuiceSSH from Android to the PC and it's working. I'm also forwarding the port I am trying to connect to, however I can't SSH from a PC to the other (both connected to the Android Hotspot). Have you got any soultion?